# Angular lazy loading module based on URL parameter

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 7 app, and am now setting up lazy-loaded modules based on route. I want to lazily load different modules based on a URL parameter. I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

Here is a schematic of how the UI is constructed:

[image: App UI schematic]

What I want to happen is for a path like this:

/page/type-of-items/type-of-item to load the app, then lazily load the page module, which will then lazily load correct "type-of-items" module based on the value of `:type-of-items` in the URL, which will then load the correct `:item` component based on the URL.

The problem is that when going to this URL: `/page/foo/item-a` the `NotFoundPageComponent` gets rendered. What am I doin incorrectly here?

This is my current set of routing modules:

**app-routing.module:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'page',
    loadChildren: './page.module#PageModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundPageComponent
  }
];
```

**page.module:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':type-of-items',
    component: PageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'foo',
    loadChildren: '../foo.module#FooModule'
  }
];
```

Note that the `PageComponent` needs to know the value of `:type-of-items` in order to acquire some contextual data, which is why it is parameterized. In this case, the value of that is "foo".

**foo.module:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FooComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'item-a',
        component: ItemAComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'item-b',
        component: ItemBComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: My guess is that in your `page.module` routes, the path is being matched to `':type-of-items'` path and doesn't have a chance to get to `'foo'`.  Flip the order of the route in `page.module` with the most specific first.

Comment: Thanks @JasonWhite, but that gives the same result.

Comment: Is the foo module inside the page module? or are they at the same directory level?  The reason I ask is the lazy load path for foo module is `../` and not `./`.

Comment: I simplified the paths to the modules. I am not worried about whether the paths are correct, as an error would be thrown if I had the paths incorrect - and I am not seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', 
  component: SomeTopLevelComponent, // might not need
  children: [{
    path: 'page',
    loadChildren: './page.module#PageModule'
  }]},
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundPageComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: Also, when I give the location of my module, I have to start from 'app/modules/moduleName.module#moduleNameModule'